# laravel empty collection from database

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why am I getting an empty collection here. In the past, it was work for me but why am I getting this now? Where am I doing wrong?

```
public function test($id){
    //dd($id);
    $test = DB::table('images')->select('name')->where('user_id', $id)->get();
    dd($test);
}
```

And it return me this:

```
Collection {#402 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

I have already defined my route already:

```
Route::get('/test/{id}', ['as'=>'create', 'uses'=>'testController@test']);
```

I did a `dd($id)` and it return me the id I wanted so that part is correct and when I do `DB::table('images')0>select('name')->get();` it return me my data so it has been passed but once I try to add in the id it doesn't work.

I even tried doing something like this but doesn't work:

```
$test = DB::table('images')->join('user1s', 'user1s.id', '=', 'images.user_id')->select('images.name')->where('images.user_id', 'user1s.id')->get();
```

Relationship:

> user1s hasOne Images

Comment: I think `$id` is not matched with `user_id` and that's why you didn't get the results!

Comment: Oh my god you are right, I forgot to check the user_id, I was too focused on $id already. Thank you so much @HirenGohel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `$id` is not matched with `user_id` in your DB, your query is fine and so that's why you didn't get the results!

Try with `user_id` which is available in your DB, something like:

```
public function test($id){
    $test = DB::table('images')->select('name')->where('user_id', $id)->get();  //take $id which is user_id available in your DB 
    dd($test);
}
```

Hope this helps you and understandable you!!